# VBA Excel: Freeze when add Auto Save line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which checks "before save" event whether user fill mandatory cells.
When I tried to add additional line for give file to an automated name, code freezes. Yet create the file. Below you can find my code, most of the code is just checking the cells, but I'm not sure the reason of error, so I'm adding all of it in case there's something I missed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim message As String
Dim say As Long

say = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("C:C"))

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("D:D")) <> say Then
   message = Range("D1").Value & vbCrLf
End If
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("F:F")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("F1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("G:G")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("G1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("H:H")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("H1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("I:I")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("I1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("J:J")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("J1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("K:K")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("K1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("M:M")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("M1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("N:N")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("N1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("Q:Q")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("Q1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("R:R")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("R1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ACC REQ").Range("AU:AU")) <> say Then
   message = message & Range("AU1").Value & vbCrLf
End If

If message <> "" Then
   MsgBox "" & message & vbCrLf & "Can’t Save with Empty Cells!!"

Cancel = True
End If


ThisFile = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "__" & "ACC__" & Range("H2").Value & "__" & "CR"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

regards

Comment: Unrelated to your questions: generally when there's repetition in code, there's an better way to organize it.  It would be good to look into `With..End With` as well as how to loop code.

Comment: Now that I've tidied your code (below ), I've re-read your question and I'm not sure what the problem is because you haven't said what line you're trying to add, where you're adding it, or what error it's giving you.  Perhaps if you try "whatever it is" you're trying to do with the more [compact version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113086) of your code, you could have more luck.  Other than that, **more information** will be needed in your question.  (See "[ask]" as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.)

Answer (score 0):

> ### Solution:
>
> Put `Cancel=True` at the end of the procedure to keep Excel from freezing due to an infinite loop.

When you save the file, the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event runs *before Excel saves the file** like it normally would.

This can be prevented with `Cancel=True`, which is necessary in this case since you want to `SaveAs` it yourself.

Without `Cancel=True`, your `SaveAs` is triggered the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event again, where you `SaveAs` again which triggers the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event again....etc....

---

### Alternative (more compressed):

Your code should work with the change above, but below is a way to compress the code further by removing repetition.  (See also, how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

The size reduction is because of the use of `With..End With` and looping through a static array to avoid repeating the same code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim msg As String, say As Long, ws As Worksheet, col
  Set ws = Worksheets("ACC REQ")
  With Application.WorksheetFunction
    say = .CountA(ws.Columns("C"))
    For Each col In Array("D","F","G","H","I","J","K","M","N","Q","R","AU")
      If .CountA(ws.Columns(col))<>say Then msg=msg & Range(col & "1") & vbCrLf
    Next col
    Cancel = True  'we don't need Excel to save it
  End With
  If msg <> "" Then
      MsgBox msg, , "Can't Save with Empty Cells!": Exit Sub
  End If
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") _
              & "__ACC__" & Range("H2") & "__CR.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you were to add an Else to the If msg <> "" and add the last two lines to it, I believe this would be an answer to the OPs question... :)

Comment: Oh i figured it out.... Endless loop.  This is a **BeforeSave event** and you're specifying  **`SaveAs`** within in., which triggers the **BeforeSave event** again.

Comment: Hello ashleedawg thank you for your help. My VBA knowledge is limited but thanks for the link I'll check it and sorry for misunderstanding. I'm trying to check for empty cells and then save the file with predefined name. In my case "ormat(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "__ACC__" & Range("H2") & "__CR.xlsx"  @Xabier thank you for your help too. ashleedawg I tried to use your alternative solution but it didn't save the file with predefined name. In your code you wrote "ws As Worksheet, col" but statement for col isn't here, could it be the reason of error?

Answer (score 0):

This one took me a minute but I know what's the problem! You have an Event that is called BeforSave in which you save. Which means that you have the Event within it self. This causes an infinite loop.

Do this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim message As String
Dim say As Long
Dim ThisFile As String
Dim Path As String

'.. Check stuff ..


Path = "C:\YourPath\YourFolder\"
ThisFile = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "__" & "ACC__" & Range("H2").Value & "__" & "CR"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile & ".xlsm"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Cancel = True
```

End Sub

This should solve your problems as it disables the events for the duration of the actual saving. Make sure that you have the `Application.EnableEvents=True` otherwise it will not fire at all.

Comment: Good thinking but note that the document will be saved twice in this case since Excel will sill save the document again after the end of the `BeforeSave` event (unless the Excel's attempt at saving is cancelled using `Cancel=True`.)

Comment: @ ashleedawg Yeah you would then need to add  `cancle=True` at the end of the sub true.

Comment: Hello @ Lucas Raphael Pianegonda sorry but I couldn't run your code. nothing happen when I clicked save or save as button.

Comment: @user3551927 please make sure that `Application.EnableEvents=True` otherwise the BeforeSave will not trigger and nothing will happen other than saving.

Comment: Hello @Lucas Raphael Pianegonda it is true but still don't work. `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile & ".xlsx"
Application.EnableEvents = True
Cancel = True`